# Embedded Assembler block in Clion

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly, clion

i know that i can use this syntax in Microsoft Visual C++ if i want to use some assembly

```
__asm {                         
    MOV EAX, iCislo                 
    INC EAX                         
    MOV iVysledok,EAX                
    }
```

I also found version for gcc compiler.

```
   asm(".intel_syntax noprefix \n"   
       "mov eax,_iCislo        \n"   
       "inc eax                \n"  
       "mov _iVysledok,eax     \n"  
       ".att_syntax            \n");
```

Is it possible use something like that in CLion? Or is it better to download Microsoft Visual C++ for the purposes? I use CLion for C so i would like to find if is it possible in CLion too. Thank you very much for responds.

Comment: CLion appears to be an IDE and not a compiler, so it'll depend on what compiler you use with.  Also note that the GCC example you posted is broken and is not quite the same as the Visual C++ example because GCC will assume EAX (and all other registers) aren't modified by the inline assembly statement.

Comment: GCC will also assume that `iVysledok` isn't modified by the inline asm, because there's no `"memory"`  clobber.  For that particular snippet, there's no reason at all to do it with asm; the compiler will do a better job if you give it pure C like `iCislo = iVysledok+1;`  **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLion is not a compiler, but an IDE, it uses GCC or Clang compilers as its toolchain, and Clang in-line assembly syntax is the same as GCC's (see https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm).

Comment: You gave the link for clang, [here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) the one for gcc.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd GCC and MSVC syntax were mentioned in the question. The purpose of the link was not to provide syntax but a link to the clang documentation on GCC comparability.